# Confused with the DLL Azure Storage DLL

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I am trying to create table in Storage but the issue is that when i use class `CloudStorageAccount` this class is available in both using `Microsoft.WindowsAzure`;
using `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage`; i am not sure if there is any conflict between the DLL, I have both V1.7 and V2.0 present on the machine.

i have used the code

```cs
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConn"));

Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

string tableName = "People";
// che = tableClient.CreateTableIfNotExist(tableName);
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table.CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference(tableName);
table.CreateIfNotExists();
```

but Server returns the Error 400 i am not sure where i am going wrong

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. Can you share the value of `StorageConn`? Please strip out any sensitive details before posting.

Comment: DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=Name;AccountKey=9hIBsgmHfN+vKjTm3HoNOIAehTl2YD8B2UNnOVgWZXBlfyTkft+UPJjJJSwSsiNjVIbQjKOGd0nos/pL8lLA==

Comment: I feel issue with the SDK... i have both 1.7 and 2.0 on my laptop

Comment: What I would recommend is that you get rid of reference of 1.7 version of the library from your code as your code is only using 2.0 version. That would reduce some confusion. Secondly I would recommend tracing your request through Fiddler. You will get detailed error message in Fiddler response which will provide you more information. HTH.

Comment: i have done as per your comment but issue still remain in the fiddler it showing <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code>ResourceNotFound</code>
  <message xml:lang="en-US">The specified resource does not exist.
RequestId:880576a7-1ec9-4df7-8f10-a3b81a39ce6a
Time:2013-08-03T14:46:56.5574126Z</message>
</error>

Comment: i have created the new storage account in the azure do i need to enable it  after creating

Comment: ResourceNotFound error should be 404 error and not 400 as you mentioned in your post. Please check the name of the storage account. Also please ensure that you're passing the storage account name in **lowercase**. If you provide that in upper or mixed case, That might give 400 error. Regarding your 2nd comment, No you don't need to do anything to enable it. HTH.

Comment: resolved it, issue with the Storage Account name thanks for the help Mantri